# Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in Form Check box

Tags: php, html, sql

Been struggling with this some time now and is probably something simple...

I keep getting the following error whilst trying to submit a contact form

> Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in .... on line 240.

HTML CODE

```
<input type="checkbox" name="socialmedia[]" value="Facebook">Facebook<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="socialmedia[]" value="Twitter">Twitter<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="socialmedia[]" value="YouTube">YouTube<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="socialmedia[]" value="Flickr">Flickr<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="socialmedia[]" value="Vimeo">Vimeo<br>
```

PHP CODE

```
$socialmedia = array();
$socialmedia = implode(",",$_POST['socialmedia']);
```

Any Ideas anyone?

Comment: Well, what do you pass in there?

Comment: Check $_POST['socialmedia'] - is it an array?

Comment: Show us the result of `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Check into the awesome number of vars of your PHP code - is `$_POST['socialmedia']` set? Does you form have the proper `post` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="socialmedia[]" value="Facebook">Facebook<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="socialmedia[]" value="Twitter">Twitter<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="socialmedia[]" value="YouTube">YouTube<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="socialmedia[]" value="Flickr">Flickr<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="socialmedia[]" value="Vimeo">Vimeo<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?
$socialmedia = array();
if(isset($_POST['socialmedia'])) $socialmedia = implode(",",$_POST['socialmedia']);
print_r($socialmedia);
?>
```

only change is additional checking `if(isset($_POST['socialmedia']))` before imploding the array

Comment: Not sure why someone did a -1: this is a correct solution and is not really different than the corresponding line in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this before when the user didn't check any boxes.  The reason you get a warning is because `$_POST['socialmedia']` doesn't actually exist if no checkboxes are checked.  You are effectively calling `implode(",", NULL);`

---

To get the selected checkboxes in a string:

```
$checkboxes = !empty($_POST['socialmedia']) ? $_POST['socialMedia'] : array();
$socialmedia = implode(',' $checkboxes);
```

---

It seems like you might want them in an array.  It's hard to tell from your question. If you want them in an array you can just do:

```
$socialmedia = !empty($_POST['socialmedia']) ? $_POST['socialMedia'] : array();
```

`$socialmedia` will then be an empty array if no checkboxes were checked or will contain the values of the checkboxes.

Comment: I would be inclined to use `empty($_POST['socialmedia']) ? array() : $_POST['socialMedia'];`.